# Group and lock certain windows to a workspace in Gnome 3

Tags: fedora, gnome3, window-manager, window, workspaces

Is it possible to group certain windows to always occupy the same area and always be in the same workspace?  If so, how?

For example I'm using Eclipse and I have multiple detached windows and for some reason lots of times these windows get move between workspaces and moved around too. I would like to keep them all on workspace 1 for example.

Answer (score 3):

Devil's Pie? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie

Comment: `devil's pie` is a doing a great job with all the applications that I wanted except for `Eclipse`. I'm still working to see if I can tweak it to work. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: For me this also works with Eclipse (4.2.1) on Fedora 17 with Gnome 3. Great tool!